# Do these multiplicative functions exist?

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization, roots-of-unity, mobius-function, multiplicative-function

I read about the multiplicative function $\mu$ defined by Möbius. Which is for any given $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such as $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot ....\cdot p_r^{\alpha_r}$ is defined as
$$\mu(n)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             0 &   \text{ if there is } 1\leq i \leq r \text{ such as } \alpha_i\geq 2
             \\ 1 &  \text{ if } n=1
             \\ (-1)^r &  \text{ any other case }
             \end{array}
   \right.$$
Now this raises the question that if these functions have already been defined.
For any fixated $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and the same $n\in \mathbb{N}$ as before, we define.
$$\mu_k(n)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             0 &   \text{ if there is } 1\leq i \leq r \text{ such as } \alpha_i\geq k
             \\ 1 &  \text{ if } n=1 
             \\ e^{\frac{2 \pi i m}{k}} & \text{ any other case.}
             \end{array}
   \right.$$
Being $m=\Omega(n)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^r \alpha_i$
It would make sense that this is the case, since these functions are all defined in the roots of unity, which is similar to the original $\mu$ and also multiplicative, but I can't seem to find them anywhere. Can anyone tell me if I'm correct?

Comment: So you are defining a *multiplicative* function $f(n)$ such that $f(p^k)=0$ and $f(p^m)=e^{2\pi im/k}$ for $m\lt k$. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function for definition of "multiplicative" function.)

Answer (score 1):

Note $u_1(n)=|u_k(n)|=|\mu(n)|$ (see [OEIS Entry A008966](https://oeis.org/A008966)), and $u_2(n)=\mu(n)$ (see [OEIS Entry A008683](https://oeis.org/A008683)).

With respect to $u_k(n)$ more generally, the Dirichlet characters $\chi_{k,j}(n)$ are of much greater theoretical interest (see [Wikipedia: Dirichlet Characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_character) and [MathWorld: Number Theoretic Character](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NumberTheoreticCharacter.html)).